# Neo4j: How to match relationship?

Tags: database, facebook-graph-api, graph, neo4j, graph-databases

For example:
I know a person A who is connected to another person B
and person B is connected to person C

How can i show that person A is indirectly connected to person C?

Comment: on stackoverflow, you are required to add what you have tried so far. either way, what you want to achieve is not possible, at least not anymore. you can only check for friend status between users who authorized your app, so user A, B and C would have to authorize your app with the user_friends permission.

Answer (score 0):

You're question doesn't contain any code/query sample, so I made some assumptions and just give you an example how I should approach this:

```
MATCH (personA:Person)-[:HAS_FRIEND]->(personB:Person)
WITH personA, personB
OPTIONAL MATCH (personB)-[:HAS_FRIEND]->(personC:Person)
WITH personA, personB, collect(distinct personC) AS friendsOfPersonB
RETURN personA, personB, friendsOfPersonB
```